# How to change sort direction in magento admin for categories product

Tags: magento-1.7, sorting, category-products

In magento `$this->setDefaultSort('position');` sorts the grid by 'position' column but in descending order. How can I change its sorting order to Ascending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it by searching in Magento files.

use `$this->setDefaultDir('ASC');` to set direction.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, so that the question does not count as "unanswered" anymore